# MEPS Priority Conditions ICD-10 Codes

Tags: medical

Medical Expenditure Panel Survey has a list of [priority conditions (A3-1, last page)](https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/download_data/pufs/h199/h199doc.pdf):

LIST OF CONDITIONS ASKED IN PRIORITY CONDITIONS ENUMERATION SECTION

- Angina/Angina Pectoris

  Arthritis

  Asthma

  Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder (ADHD)/Attention Deficit
  Disorder (ADD)

  Cancer/Malignancy

  Chronic Bronchitis

  Coronary Heart Disease

  Diabetes/Sugar Diabetes

  Emphysema

  Heart Attack/Myocardial Infarction (MI)

  High Cholesterol

  Hypertension/High Blood Pressure

  Joint Pain

  Other Heart Disease (not coronary heart disease, angina, or heart
  attack)

  Stroke/Transient Ischemic Attack (TIA)/Mini-stroke

I would like to filter out any non-priority conditions events then group by priority condition. The conditions are given in a [table with ranges of 2-3 digit CCS codes](https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/conditions.shtml). The latest (2017) MEPS data provides a [reference to a mapping provided by HCUPS](https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccsr/ccs_refined.jsp) to convert the ICD10 codes to CCSR. However the CCSR codes in the mapping are 3 char + 3 digit. How can I get the groups of ICD-10 codes which map to a priority condition by the 2-3 digit CCS codes given in the [MEPS conditions table](https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/conditions.shtml)?

EDIT:

I am looking for any reasonable method to group the events into those pertaining to one of the priority conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently HCUPS provides a comparison of of the [CCSR for ICD-10-CM Diagnoses, v2019.1, to the Beta Version of the CCS for ICD-10-CM Diagnoses, v2019.1](https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccsr/DXCCSR-vs-Beta-CCS-Comparison.xlsx). I believe this version (v2019.1) is the version used in the 2017 condition file.